# Are these Windows CLI commands or Linux terminal commands?

Tags: cli, vagrant

Windows 10, Magento 2.1.

I am reading Vagrant directions so I can get VirtualBox and Magento running. These directions tell me to run commands, but they don't say where to run the commands. I have used the Windows CLI, but never the ($) character. Am I supposed to use the below commands in Windows CLI or the emulated Linux OS terminal that is running inside of VirtualBox? Thanks.

$ mkdir vagrant_getting_started

$ cd vagrant_getting_started

$ vagrant init

Here is the page with directions I am following:
https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/project_setup.html

Comment: You're supposed to run those commands on whatever your own OS is, assuming you have installed vagrant already. However, I made an easy to follow video to do exactly what you are trying to accomplish. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=qTeDLoC2rV0

Comment: Thanks. That's a good video for MAC and Linux users installing Magento 1.x. I edited my post to add that I am using Windows 10 and Magento 2.1. It looks like you have some other videos there I will watch in the future.

Comment: I apologize, I totally forgot that it wasn't valid for windows! Do you know how to add vagrant to your PATH? This way you can vagrant from any directory.

Comment: No. I have not yet installed Vagrant or VirtualBox. I was hoping to do that today if I can get up the courage.

Comment: No courage needed, both are a fairly simple install. With that being said, since you may not be terribly familiar with the command line, you should consider backing up your OS just in case.

Comment: Thanks. I have some experience with the command line; I spent a couple weeks learning Meteor. I will down load and install Vagrant and VirtualBox and then go from there.

Answer (score 1):

These must be Linux commands.
I will down load and install Vagrant and VirtualBox and then go from there.

Thanks for the help in the comments.